# Vue.js Method/Variable Extraction

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am working on a League of Legends API client using Vue.js. As I keep adding more functionality, my index.html file is becoming a bit excessive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="form" class="btn group">
      <h1>League of Legends API Client</h1>
      <p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name">

        <button @click="getBasicInfo" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Go!</button>
        <select name="region" id="region" class="custom-select" v-model="region">
          <option value="RU">RU</option>
          <option value="KR">KR</option>
          <option value="BR1">BR1</option>
          <option value="OC1">OC1</option>
          <option value="JP1">JP1</option>
          <option value="NA1">NA1</option>
          <option value="EUN1">EUN1</option>
          <option value="EUW1">EUW1</option>
          <option value="TR1">TR1</option>
          <option value="LA1">LA1</option>
          <option value="LA2">LA2</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="stats">
      <h1>Basic Info</h1>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <th scope="col">Summoner</th>
          <th scope="col">Level</th>
          <th scope="col">Icon</th>
          <th scope="col">Account ID</th>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="table-primary">
            <th scope="row">{{name}}</th>
            <td>{{level}}</td>
            <td>{{profileIconId}}</td>
            <td>{{accountId}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr>
      <h1>Recent Games</h1>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <th scope="col">Region</th>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Champion</th>
          <th scope="col">Season</th>
          <th scope="col">Role</th>
          <th scope="col">Lane</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="table-primary" v-for="game in games">
            <th scope="row">{{game.platformId}}</th>
            <td>{{game.gameId}}</td>
            <td>{{game.champion}}</td>
            <td>{{game.season}}</td>
            <td>{{game.role}}</td>
            <td>{{game.lane}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const request = require("request")
  const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      API_KEY: "apikeyhere",
      region: "",
      profileIconId: '',
      name: '',
      level: '',
      accountId: '',
      id: '',
      games: []
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
      getBasicInfo: function () {
        var app = this
        let url = "https://" + app.region + ".api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + app.name +
          "?api_key=" + app.API_KEY
        axios.get(url)
          .then(function (response) {
            const data = response.data
            app.profileIconId = data.profileIconId
            app.level = data.summonerLevel
            app.accountId = data.accountId
            app.id = data.id
            url = "https://" + app.region + ".api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matchlists/by-account/" + app.accountId +
              "/recent?api_key=" + app.API_KEY
            axios.get(url)
              .then(function (response) {
                app.games = response.data.matches
                for (i = 0; i < app.games.length; i++) {
                  console.log(app.games[i].lane)
                }
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
              })
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          })

      },
      goToRecentGames: function () {
        location.href = `file://${__dirname}/recent.html`
      }
    }
  })
</script>

</html>
```

I am wondering what is the correct way to go about extracting some of this code to separate files. This may be a simple answer, as I am fairly new to web development in general.

Comment: You are new but fact is you can make separate js files and include it but still html will grow more and more ... Your real solution will be module bundler like webpack .. you should learn it and start using it. https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/

Comment: Additionally, you can look into extract certain functionality and encapsulating it as a separate reusable vue component. By defining these components in separate JS files, composing components together, and using `$emit` and `props` for inter-component communication, you can greatly reduce the complexity of each individual piece and keep distinct pieces of functionality completely separate for maintainability.